# EXPECT_EQ Error

Tags: c++, googletest

I'm using the google test function EXPECT_EQ to run a test case for a function. The function, "find" returns a list and takes in a string of the name to find. Here's my test function:

```
TEST_F(test_neighborhood, find) {
    list<Man> test;
    test.push_back(Man("username", "John", "Smith", 1, 1, ""));
    EXPECT_EQ(neighborhood.find("John"), test);
}
```

But when I try to "make", it gives me a long error
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/algorithm:665:71: error: invalid
      operands to binary expression ('const Man' and 'const Man')
    bool operator()(const _T1& __x, const _T1& __y) const {return __x == __y;}

Am I not using EXPECT_EQ correctly? How do I fix this error?

Answer (score 1):

`EXPECT_EQ` requires equality operator to be defined for passed items. `std::list` already has such an operator calling equality operator for each stored item. So it seems that you need to define `operator ==` to compare two instances of `Man` class for equality:

```
bool operator ==(Man const & left, Man const & right)
```

Comment: Hi, do I place that line in my test function? It still throws the same error I believe

Comment: You have to define it in the `Man` class

Comment: No, you need to place it along with `Man` class definition, see [What are the basic rules and idioms for operator overloading?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421706/what-are-the-basic-rules-and-idioms-for-operator-overloading).

Comment: I think I'm still confused about where to place it (I placed in the Man's header class file within the class definition and tried both public and private) but I get this error in addition to the original: ./inc/man.h:21:10: error: overloaded 'operator==' must be a binary operator
      (has 3 parameters)
    bool operator ==(Man const & left, Man const & right);

Comment: @user90823745 It should be a free function in the same namespace. Typically it is declared either outside of class in the same header or inside of the class as a `friend`.

Comment: @VTT I put it outside and after the class definition in the header file but I get the error: Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:  "operator==(Person const&, Person const&)", referenced from:.... ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64

Comment: @user90823745 is `Man` class actually called `Person`? Did you forget to write operator definition?

Comment: @VTT Sorry about that - I meant "operator==(Man const&, Man const&)", Person is a different object that basically has the same problem as this one